# Git not installed in VSCode on MAC

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I may have accidentally deleted something when cleaning up my hard drive. Now when I bring up VS Code I get message saying GIT is not installed and GIT extentsion don't work. 
Is there a way to refresh GIT in VS Code?

Comment: Check the output of git --version. If git is not found there then try reinstall git on Mac. Then Vs Code will start to see git.

Comment: Git is not a part of vscode. Install it separately

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Reinstalled git.